# json encode not work in wordpress

Tags: ajax, json

I'm building ajax search plugin for wordpress.
I have no output when I want to convert to result to json.
Of course my plugin works without Json conversion.

(Is it okay if I don't use Json??)

my code is:

search_form.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_search2', 'ajax_search2' );    
function ajax_search2() {
    $data = array();
    $val =$_POST['val'];
    echo $val;
    if(strlen($val) > 3){
        $ppp = 6;
        $post_type = 'product';
        $args = array(
            's' => $val,
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'posts_per_page' => $ppp
        );
        $query = new WP_Query($args);
            
        if($query->have_posts()){
            while($query->have_posts()){
                $query->the_post();
                $link=get_permalink( get_the_ID() );
                $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'thumbnail'); 
                $thumb = $thumb[0];
                $data['product'] .= '<li><img src="'.$thumb.'"><span><a href="'.$link.'">'.$query->post->post_title.'</a></span></li>';
        }
            
        if($query->found_posts > 6){
            $data['product'] .= '<li class="more"><a href="'.site_url().'/?s='.$val.'&post_type='.$post_type.'">ادامه</a></li>';
            // 'the post font after 6';
        }
         wp_reset_postdata();
    }else{
        $data['product'] = "no product found2";
    }
        
    }
    $result = wp_json_encode($data);
    wp_send_json($result);// 
}
```

---

ajax.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //alert('this is a test for ajax');
    $(window).click(function(){
        
        $('.box-search').css('opacity','0');
    })
    $('.box-search').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    })
    
    var SearchReq = null;
    
    $('.search .search-field').keyup(function(){
        $('.box-search').css('opacity','1');
        var val = $('.search .search-field').val();
        ajaxSearch(val);
    })
    
    function ajaxSearch(val){
        
        if( val.length < 3){
            $('.box-search').css('opacity','0');
            return;
        }
        SearchReq = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType : "json",
            url:'http://ferfri.ir/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data:{
                action : 'ajax_search2',
                val : val
            },beforeSend:function(){
                $('.box-search ul').html('قبل از ارسال');
                if(SearchReq != null){
                    SearchReq.abort();
                }
            },success:function(res){
                res = JSON.parse(res);
                $('.box-search ul.product').html(res.product);
                $('.box-search ul.news').html(res);
                
            }
        })
    }
    
});
```

Comment: have you considered using the REST API instead of the old legacy admin-ajax.php API? The REST API is built for these kinds of requests and handles JSON directly, as well as giving you a lot of other things such as pretty URLs. You might find that your product post type already has a REST API endpoint you can query to grab data from in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_send_json()` already converts the value to JSON, so you don't need to do it again. You can remove `wp_json_encode()`.

Comment: Hi, thank , but it still does not work